# Trying to set up Full Text Search for SQL Server Via Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to set up SQL full Text Search by script (no GUI)
I have been looking on the internet but I cant find a answer that works for me.

I have a simple table (ive simplified it) below that i want to use Full Text Search on:

```
     DownloadTable
     ID int primary key idenity,
     Title varchar(30),
     Description varchar(100),
     Category Varchar(100),
     URL varchar(100)
```

this is what I have done

```
     /*Enable Full Text Search*/
     EXEC sp_fulltext_database enable

     /*Create Search Catalog*/
     CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MySearchCat
     WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
     AUTHORIZATION [dbo]

     /*Create Full Text Index
     CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo]. [DownloadTable]
     (Title ,Description)
     KEY INDEX iD ON [Test]
     WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
     GO
```

this is where i get stuck? is the Key Index suppose to be from my Download Table and there for be download.id? or is it suppose to be on the search catalog? I cant just make up a name as it doesnt work? but I cant use ID either?

Answer (score 4):

```
create table 
DownloadTable (
     ID int identity, constraint pk_DownloadTable primary key (id),
     Title varchar(30),
     Description varchar(100),
     Category Varchar(100),
     URL varchar(100)
     )
 /*Create Search Catalog*/
     CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MySearchCat
     WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
     AUTHORIZATION [dbo]


     CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo]. [DownloadTable]
     (Title ,Description)
     KEY INDEX pk_DownloadTable ON MySearchCat
     WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
     GO
```